# run a php script in background

Tags: php, symfony

I have a php scrip, in which i have written the following code

```
$client = new \Predis\Client();
$client->select(4);
$client->lpush('emailid',$x['to']);


$command = "/usr/bin/php5 -f /var/www/Symfony/src/Ens/NewBundle/Controller/cron.php";

exec( "$command > /dev/null &", $arrOutput );

return $this->render('EnsNewBundle:Email:header.html.twig');
```

in this I have written an another php script named as `cron.php`. I want to run that script in background. and I want to check that is this running in background or not. how can i check that

Comment: possible duplicate of [php execute a background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the output of cron in a file by  `> filename` and check if it really runs.

Or check in process list if there is a new php process stating when you run this one.

You should also look at Codememe bundle [here](https://github.com/CodeMeme/CodeMemeDaemonBundle)

Do check open source queuing systems too, they are helpful many times.
Like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) or RabbitMQ

You can push data to these queues, they can be say "filenames" and other worker takes data from the "tubes" of queues and apply say "php filename" and then picks up next data from queue.

Comment: when i m running on command line `php test.php` then it is giving correct answer but when i am running this command  in another php file as follow: `echo shell_exec('php test.php | /dev/null &');` then it is giving no answer

Comment: when you do shell_exec the process starts in background, so take some standard output from test.php to a file using `shell_exec('php test.php > file');` , you don't need '&' here. And check if test.php returned successfully using echoing something at file termination, which will be stored in file

Comment: this is not giving any response

Comment: when i am running whoami directly in this exec() then its giving correct ans but when i am execution this in test,php and executing test,php in index.php then it is giving blank

Comment: is test.php made to do anything? try something like sexec("mkdir dir") in test.php and check whether it is running or not.

Comment: this is my test.php  `$output=shell_exec('whoami');
echo $output;
`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could have a look to the [Symfony2 Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

It's quite useful for running command from PHP.